# Почему курсор не проходит через невидимые преграды?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, консоль

Игровое поле сделано через Матрицу 25 на 25. Идея в том, что есть игровое поле, в котором есть края и преграды через которые курсор не должен проходить. Свободное пространство сделано через char элемент ' '(пробел), стенки и преграды через char элемент '#'. Передвижение курсора('@' char элемент) осуществляется клавишами W, A, S, D. Все стенки и преграды, как и свободное пространство, сделаны из одного элемента, путем присвоения значения определенным элементам матрицы данных переменных( ' ', '#').

ПРОБЛЕМА:
В некоторых местах поля курсор просто не проходит, а должен. А в некоторых местах проходит через преграды, хотя не должен. Все элементы как преграды, так и свободного пространства сделано из одного элемента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
void Cursor(int, int);

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    int y = 1;

    char s = ' ';
    char w = '#';

    bool Game = true;
    // МАТРИЦЯ. 
    const int length = 25; // Розміри матриці.
    char mas[length][length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
            /* Один елемент матриці це 3 строкових елементи з клавіатури, чи букви,
            чи символи, чи пробіли.*/
            mas[i][j] = s;  // Заповнення пустого місця.
            mas[length - 1][j] = w; // Нижній рядок.
            mas[0][j] = w; // Верхній рядок.
            mas[i][length - 1] = w; // Правий стовбчик 
            mas[i][0] = w;          //  Лівий стовбчик 
            //mas[0][length - 1] = " ";
        };
    };
    // ПЕРЕШКОДИ В СЕРЕДИНІ ІГРОВОГО ПОЛЯ
                // Вертикальні перешкоди.
                // 2 стовбчик
    for (int i = 5; i < 9; i++) {
        mas[i][2] = w;
    };
    //6 стовбчик
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
        mas[i][6] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 15; i < 21; i++) {
        mas[i][6] = w;
    };
    //10 стовбчик
    for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
        mas[i][10] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 9; i < 14; i++) {
        mas[i][10] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 16; i < 23; i++) {
        mas[i][10] = w;
    };
    //15 стовбчик
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        mas[i][15] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 9; i < 12; i++) {
        mas[i][15] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 17; i < 24; i++) {
        mas[i][14] = w;
    };
    // 19 стовбчик.
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        mas[i][18] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 8; i < 14; i++) {
        mas[i][19] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 19; i < 23; i++) {
        mas[i][19] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 8; i < 20; i++) {
        mas[i][22] = w;
    };
    // ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНІ РЯДКИ.
            // 2 рядок.
    for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
        mas[2][i] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 12; i < 14; i++) {
        mas[2][i] = w;
    };
    // 4 рядок.
    for (int i = 2; i < 5; i++) {
        mas[4][i] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 19; i < 22; i++) {
        mas[4][i] = w;
    };
    // 6 рядок.
    for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
        mas[6][i] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 18; i < 24; i++) {
        mas[6][i] = w;
    };
    // 8 рядок.
    for (int i = 19; i < 21; i++) {
        mas[8][i] = w;
    };
    // 10 рядок.
    for (int i = 2; i < 6; i++) {
        mas[10][i] = w;
    };
    // 13 рядок.
    for (int i = 12; i < 16; i++) {
        mas[13][i] = w;
    };
    // 15 рядок.
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
        mas[15][i] = w;
    };
    // 17 рядок.
    for (int i = 14; i < 20; i++) {
        mas[17][i] = w;
    };
    // 23 рядок.
    for (int i = 9; i < 11; i++) {
        mas[23][i] = w;
    };
    for (int i = 19; i < 23; i++) {
        mas[23][i] = w;
    };

    while (Game == true) {
        system("CLS");
        // ВИВІД МАТРИЦІ.
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                cout << mas[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        };
        Cursor(x, y);
        char wad = _getch();
        if (wad == 'w')
        {
            if (mas[x][y - 1] == s)
            {
                y = --y;
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
            else if (mas[x][y - 1] != s)
            {
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
        }
        else if (wad == 'a') 
        {
            if (mas[x - 1][y] == s) 
            {
                x = --x;
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
            else if (mas[x - 1][y] != s)
            {
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
        }
        else if (wad == 'd') 
        {
            if (mas[x + 1][y] == s) 
            {
                x = ++x;
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
            else if (mas[x + 1][y] != s)
            {
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
        }
        else if (wad == 's') 
        {
            if ((mas[x][y + 1]) == s) 
            {
                y = ++y;
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
            else if (mas[x][y + 1] != s)
            {
                Cursor(x, y);
            }
        }
        else if (wad == 'q')
        {
            Game = false;
        };
    }
}


void Cursor(int X, int Y) {
    COORD cord;
    cord.X = X;
    cord.Y = Y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), cord);
    char curs = '@';
    cout << curs;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Знакомая задача! :) Хорошо, что послушали совет и массив сделали `char[][]`.
А вообще - всё очень просто. Вы перепутали `X` и `Y`. В матрице `mas[][]` чтобы двигаться по горизонтали нужно менять значение столбца, а чтобы по-вертикали - строки. Вы пишете `mas[x][y]`, а надо `mas[y][x]`. Т.е. чтобы сдвинуть курсор вправо нужно увеличить индекс по столбцам `mas[y][x++]`, а если вниз - то по строкам `mas[y++][x]`.
Ещё несколько улучшений. Поскольку вы в матрице храните картинку поля, можно отказаться от функции `Cursor()` и рисовать курсор прямо в матрицу mas[y][x]=`@`; и стирать его так же в матрице mas[y][x]= ; Потом когда матрица будет выводиться на экран, сразу выведется и курсор.
Ну и огромный блок с `if() ... else` можно переписать более компактно

```
    const char s = ' ';
    const char w = '#';
    const char curs = '@';

    while (Game == true) 
    {
        system("CLS");
        mas[y][x] = curs; // нарисовать курсор в матрице!!! по текущим координатам
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) // нарисовать матрицу на экран сразу с курсором в нужном месте
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) 
                cout << mas[i][j];
            cout << endl;
        };
        mas[y][x] = s; // стереть курсор в матрице!!! по текущим координатам
        
        char wad = _getch();
        if (wad == 'w' && mas[y - 1][x] == s)
        {
            --y;
        }
        else if (wad == 'a' && mas[y][x - 1] == s) 
        {
            --x;
        }
        else if (wad == 'd' && mas[y][x + 1] == s) 
        {
            ++x;
        }
        else if (wad == 's' && mas[y + 1][x] == s) 
        {
            ++y;
        }
        else if (wad == 'q')
        {
            Game = false;
        };
    }
```

Ну и то, что я писал в прошлый раз - `y = ++y;` это то же самое, что `++y;`
PS. Возможно поле игры проще (нагляднее) создавать вот так, чем через циклы. Всегда можно подправить, добавить/убавить стенок. И вывод матрицы упрощается - вместо посимвольного, становится построчным.

```
    char mas[length][length+1] = {
"#########################",
"#              #  #     #",
"# #####     ## #  #     #",
"#         #    #  #     #",
"# ###     #    #  ####  #",
"# #   #   #    #        #",
"# #####        #  #######",
"# #   #        #        #",
"# #   #            ## # #",
"#     #   #    #   #  # #",
"# ####    #    #   #  # #",
"#         #    #   #  # #",
"#         #        #  # #",
"#         # ####   #  # #",
"#                     # #",
"########              # #",
"#     #               # #",
"#     #               # #",
"#     #               # #",
"#     #               # #",
"#     #                 #",
"#                       #",
"#                       #",
"#                       #",
"#########################"
    };

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) // нарисовать матрицу на экран
   cout << mas[i] << "\n";
```

Столбцов на 1 больше, чтобы вместился символ 0 - конец строки.

Comment: я поняв в чем моя ошибка была. Я назвал координаты Х и У, и совсем забыл, что ето матрица, а я все с точки зрения Декартовой системы координат делал. Спасибо за свежий взгляд)